# ASP.NET Core React project template - how to link to C# backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I am trying to learn how to create React applications with ASP.NET Core. Helpfully they provide the React project template which some examples that enable me to see how everything is working together. However, in order to make sure I fully understand, I want to add my own code. I'm starting v. small with "Hello World" - I just want this displayed on the home page.

Here is my home.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Home extends Component {
static displayName = Home.name;

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { message: "" };

        fetch('Home/Index')
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then((result) => {
           this.setState({ message: result.message });
         });
    }

        render () {
         return (
           <div>
             <h1>Message:{this.state.message}</h1>
           </div> 
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my backend code that I want to be rendered on the home page:
HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace TestingReactDotNet.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

My question is - what do I `return()` in Home.js to incorporate the code in HomeController.cs and display "hello world" ?

Apologies if this question appears to have been answered elsewhere - I use a Mac, so the file structure and Visual Studio IDE are quite different and I have struggled to understand quite a few of the tutorials/answers already out there.

Comment: You would need to do an ajax call from your react application to the .net core application's Index method and retrieve the string "Hello World" in that fashion. Once you have gotten a response, would then need to add it a variable on the react side and have it render inside the render's return statement.

Comment: Thanks so much @Chris - I have attempted to do an ajax call to the .net core application's Index method (I have edited my original post to show my attempt!) This doesn't work (it displays nothing) so I must have gone wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

For the client part, you need to make a http request from your client app to the API. The ajax request you mention in the comments, indeed. This is pretty much the same regardless of frontend library/framework you use.

There are several ways around this, but a simple out-of-the-box method - should you target modern browsers - is to use the [native Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Home extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message: '' };

    fetch('api/home/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ 
            message: data 
        });
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Another alternative on making http requests is into the [native XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or use third-party libraries like for example [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to abstract away the complexities of this.

As for the api on the server-side, I assume you understand and have configured it to be available at `api/home/`. A little bit of optimisation would make your Controller sample look like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var response = "Hello World";
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Really helpful! I have changed my code to your suggestions. However, still nothing displays on the screen :( Thank you though!

Comment: @jordantomiko Any errors in your browser console? And can you identify + put the full url to the api in your browser, to see if it gives a proper return?

Comment: The console error is: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: I've tried console.logging out what is being parsed as .json in my response.json() and for some reason the fetch request is returning what is in my index.html file rather than what is in my HomeController.cs file. Do you know why this might be?