# Call .NET Core controller method from React with values

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm new to React and I just can't find clear information on how to call a controller in my .NET Core application, send it values from the form inputs and then get a result back from it. Doesn't seem like it should be hard to do but maybe I know so little that I'm asking Google the wrong questions. Anyway...

I have a controller method that looks like this. I have called it from Postman and it seems to work.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("user")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("login/authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUserAsync([FromBody] AuthenticateUserRequest request)
    {
        ... // sends request to back-end and gets a response
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

There's a request class that looks like this, and I want the UserID and Password properties from the React form to be set here.

```
public class AuthenticateUserRequest: Request
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The response that is returned contains a list of strings which is used to authenticate the user with an identity in the controller. I want to return this list to React to show what permissions the user has.

```
public class AuthenticateUserResponse: Response
{
    public List<String> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to call it with something like this:
I got this fetch example from here: [ASP.NET Core React project template - how to link to C# backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514839/asp-net-core-react-project-template-how-to-link-to-c-sharp-backend)
but it doesn't seem to work.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    if (this.state.userId == "" || this.state.password == "") {
        alert('Please enter User ID and Password.');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        fetch('user/login/authenticate', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: {
                "UserID": this.state.userId.value,
                "Password": this.state.password.value
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
}
```

The alert never gets called and I don't know if it's doing anything at all. When I press the Submit button the form clears, and that's it.

Comment: Is this a .Net Core + React application which is created from VS?

Comment: One thing would be that you should change the HttpGet to an HttpPost and use the POST method from your front-end.

Comment: Yes, created in VS using the React template.

Comment: Are userId and password state variables objects? If not why does the code tries to access value property on each one of them?

Comment: I've changed it to post.
Also removed the .value.
The alert is printing [object Object]. Am I supposed to be able to access it like an array? Everything I'm trying gives me "undefined" so I don't know if I'm accessing it incorrectly or if it's a bogus object. Is there some way to inspect it?

Comment: If you hit F12 in Chrome Browser, developer tools, opens up. On the network tab you should be able to inspect the request to and response from the API.

Comment: I updated my response object to have a { get; set; } so the controller method is actually returning the permissions in Postman now. But when I call the exact same method in React, the authenticate is marked red in the developer tool and says "Bad Request". I've even tried changing the controller to return Ok() immediately and it still says bad request. How can this be?

Comment: @Turkeyplague, please try my post below, you should change `[FromBody]`  to 
 `[FromQuery]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use get in ajax to request the action in the `Core API`, you need to accept the parameters by using `[FromQuery]` attribute instead of [FromBody] attribute.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("login/authenticate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUserAsync([FromQuery] AuthenticateUserRequest request)
{
     ... // sends request to back-end and gets a response
    return Ok();
}
```

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#binding-source-parameter-inference).